# jQuery AJAX - Provisional headers are shown chrome

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, google-chrome

I have a registration form with 5 text fields, 15 Checkbox, and 1 input file.

**And this appearing these errors except case 1:**

**Case # 1:** When envión the form without image, and without selecting a check box, and registration is done smoothly.

**Case # 2:** If I select an image and sending the form, the form stays loading, sending the request and console shows me this Provisional headers are shown.

**Case # 3:** If I select more than 9 check boxes, also shows me the Provisional mistake headers are shown.

The strange thing is that everything works perfect local smoothly, selecting all options on the form, even if I select heavy images, these errors occur is on the production server.

**Note:** Which may be causing these problems? It will be server configurations? Increase the capacity of sending information in PHP etc ...

This happens both Chrome and Firefox browser.

Comment: Usually I have encountered this when the request is in progress. Once it completes you see the full headers. So this might be due to a slow server or you are on a slow network maybe?

Comment: @codeHeart - Thank you very much for your answer helps me a lot, because this sometimes happens and is specifically when much information is sent and I think that may be why the site is on a shared server Hostgator.